# AWS public ip with port not working for nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed nodejs in aws ubuntu 18.04 version. Added port 3000 in security Group. but node js not working in my public address with port for eg: http://3.xx.xx.xx:3000.

Note: pm2 running with node js

Comment: what is the result of curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 inside your server?

Comment: I assume you have added allow rule in security group e.g.  your ip address/32 or (Not recommended 0.0.0.0/0 ) and port 3000 ?

Comment: @AsriBadlah curl 127.0.0.1:3000 - works fine, its showing output. but usig public ip is not working

Comment: on which port are you listening your node.js server? probably 3000 right,have you opened the port in security groups to allow incoming connections on port 3000 for HTTP traffic?

Comment: Does the service listens on 0.0.0.0 or only on localhost? (curl <local_ip>, not 127.0.0.1)

Comment: What is this command output  netstat -pan | grep 3000

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171 refer this, i have added a answer too check if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is :-

1. in your backend ins**ide app.js listen on port 3000 or which ever port you wish to.**
2. Go to amazon console, got to security groups associated with your ec2 instance, `and under incoming connection add a custom tcp rule with port 3000 and source should be 0.0.0.0/0 and save it`

Answer (score 0):

Run  **netstat -pan | grep 3000**  if you noticed that node.js listen on 127.0.0.1 only not 0.0.0.0 so You can't access node.js from outside because it is listening on localhost IP i.e 127.0.0.1.
You need to configure node.js to listen on 0.0.0.0 so it will be able to accept connections on all the IPs of your machine.

For example:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/');
```

last step if you did not already, go to the Security Groups tab in the EC2 console. Right click the security group you setup and click edit inbound rules.
Click Add Rule. This time we are going to use a custom TCP rule on port 3000, open to anywhere.

Comment: I have followed these steps but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and open Inbound port in AWS Security Group:

`sudo ufw allow 3000`[image]